# Creating a Loss Function

Tags: r

I was trying to creating a loss function below. 
Where tts is the total sum of squares and x is values 1-100 and t is a given y hat. W0+W1 is supposedly par(0,1) but I'm having issues with getting the function correct but I'm not sure why.

````
x
t
loss <- function(par){
  th<-w0+w1*x
  tts<-(t-th)^2
  return(sum(tts))

}



```{r, error = TRUE}
results <- optim(par = c(0,1), fn = loss, method = 'BFGS')
results$par
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to any function that you want to optimize with `optim` must be the vector of parameters that `optim` will search over.  You named this vector `par` but then you didn't use `par` anywhere in your function.  In my example below, I'm going to call the vector of parameters `params` so as not to mix it up with the first argument to `optim` and you'll see it gets used (ie, the loss function uses `params[1]`, etc.):

```
# define loss function
loss <- function(params, x, y) {
    yhat  <- params[1] + params[2]*x
    tss <- (y - yhat)^2
    return(sum(tss))
}

# generate fake data
n <- 100
x <- 1:n
w0_true <- 2
w1_true <- 3
y <- w0_true + w1_true*x + rnorm(n)

# find w0_hat and w1_hat with optim
optim(par=c(0,1), fn=loss, x=x, y=y)

# check with lm
summary(lm(y ~ x))
```